# Silverstripe subsite redirect loops

Tags: silverstripe

I have installed `subsite` module in my Silverstripe project. I have two domains

1. login.abc.com `=>A main site`
2. login.xyz.com `=> A subsite, virtual host is created`

The problem here is I can access -

3. `login.abc.com/` and `login.abc.com/admin`
4. `login.xyz.com/admin`

But I can't access `login.xyz.com`, it causes `redirect loops`

I then tried to debug this issue on `framework\main.php`

```
DataModel::set_inst(new DataModel());
echo "This code is printed"; //This code executes
Director::direct($url, DataModel::inst());
```

I m stuck for hours to figure out what might be causing the redirect loops, but in vain. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I created another domain `login.pqr.com [Not subsite]`  and pointed to same folder and this also works properly. So the problem is clear that the issue exist only in `subsite` domain.

**UPDATE 2**

I then created `subsite` with domain with same name `login.pqr.com`. Now this time website frontend `login.pqr.com` didn't work.

**UPDATE 3**
If from `subsites` menu under  admin,  I turn off `Enable public access`, then it works.

So it seems issue in `subsite` module?? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might stumble upon this post in the future, to fix this issue -

1. We need to make sure that sub sites have `pages` created, most importantly the landing page
2. We can copy pages from the main site to the sub sites. `Subsite` module seem to have bug - `If the page you are copying has children, the children are not copied, even if there is option to copy children`

Comment: That's great that you solved your problem and shared your solution for anyone who may have the same problem in the future. Would you like to mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: @3dg00 Yes I will, but I have to wait for couple of hours before I could mark it as accepted.